# Determine ordering of windows shell context menu extension entries

Tags: c++, windows, contextmenu, shell-extensions, appxmanifest

I am trying to implement a shell extension that displays a number of entries in the windows 10/11 context menu. I have based a lot of my solution on this example: https://github.com/microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/SparsePackages

This means I am using IExplorerCommand to implement the different command handlers : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommand

Currently, in my AppxManifest.xml file, for the Directory item type, I have something that looks like the following entries:

```
  <desktop4:FileExplorerContextMenus>
    <desktop5:ItemType Type="Directory">
      <desktop5:Verb Id="FirstIdString" Clsid="MY-CLSID"/>
      <desktop5:Verb Id="SecondIdString" Clsid="MY-CLSID"/>
      <desktop5:Verb Id="ThirdIdString" Clsid="MY-CLSID"/>
      <desktop5:Verb Id="FourthIdString" Clsid="MY-CLSID"/>
    </desktop5:ItemType>
```

In the actual context menu, the entries show up in a different ordering to what I have declared here. How would I go about manipulating the index/ordering of the context menu entries?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the order in which you declare them to see if it makes any difference?  If it does, then maybe you can do that to get the menu you want.  But, ofc, it might work differently on another machine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the context menu entries are sorted and grouped based on the string value of the Id attribute of the desktop5:Verb nodes. This does not seem to be documented in the schema reference.